# Want to convert Variants from radio buttons to dropdown in Spree 1.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am using Spree 1.1.1 and now i want to have Dropdown instead of radio buttons for variants in product page.

I have gone through spree extension "spree-dropdown-variants" but, was 2 Year older GEM and I don't Know if i can use this 2 year older GEM with latest vesrion of Spree. 
and if yes the git repository of "spree-dropdown-variants" has no .gem file.so, how to install extention for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

That extension will not work with Spree 1.1.1 because it's only compatible with version Spree 0.11.x. You have to port that extension if you want it to work. I also plan to port my 'spree-dropdown-variants-by-option' gem to Spree 1.1.x but in the near future. If you urgently need the functionality, I am happy to work out a deal to port it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your intrest Mr.Trung Lê, and sorry for the late reply.

I have moved to spree_flexi_variants which worked well and completed my needs.
https://github.com/jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants